# Adding column to wp_posts table or join wp_posts table with another table

Tags: wp-query, theme-development

I need to save many details like vites, likes, dislikes, voted day, page views about posts.

**Custom Fields**? Yes, I know that custom fields are for that.

But I need to order by many multiple custom fields, and sort by any multiple custom fields and something like "**most viewed posts within last 7 days/ 30 days** and **many more** ."

Above things are too complex and some are impossible doing with `pre_get_posts` filter with custom fields.

So I would like to add those things as coloums to `wp_posts` **or** use separate table and join it with `wp_posts`.

If I did above thing is there way to order posts by those added columns with `pre_get_posts`?

Or **can I use totally different loop instead of  default WordPress loop ( I mean that I create custom queries instead of using WP Query?**